# iOS SwfitUI set background image for list not cell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to give my ListView a background image which should not be for every cell. So only one image for the whole view.
I have tried to add `.background(Image("nameOfImage))` as list modifier but did not do anything.

```
NavigationView {
    List(elements) { element in 
        NavigationLink(destination: NextView) {
            Text(element.name)
            Image(element.image)
        }
    }.background(Image("nameOfImage"))
}
```

I have also tried a ZStack but I think the list overlays my image

So how can I put an image as list background or view background (the code above is the whole view)

Comment: If this is for macOS the post [SwiftUI background color of List Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60467330/12299030) can be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It did the thing, but the point is that `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` have default white `backgroundColor`. You should make them transparent to see through.

Something like:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // For tableView
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear // For tableViewCell
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0...10, id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(number)")
            }.background(Image("BG"))
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that I have simplified my answer to make it independent from other parts of your project</sub>

Comment: thank you but as I'm still a beginner in iOS programming I tried it like you did. But this created two errors which I couldn't remove: `Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'` and `Initializers may only be declared within a type`

Comment: Sorry my bad. I’m on the mobile and It’s kind of hard to write code here :) I have updated mu answer

Comment: I have tried it too before you showed me but I'm getting another error: `Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`

Can you help me again? Don't get it

Comment: That is not related to the question my friend. You probably forgot to assign value to all of your stored properties. I have simplified my answer to make it independent from other parts of your project and make it a working example.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy for three days. I've searched everywhere. Seems a lot harder than it should be. How many would think of turning off UI... Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Typical swiftui, nothing works or it's changed or everything's outdated. Something so simple is so frustrating