# SwiftUI: Background color of List with SidebarListStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI `List` that has its `listStyle` set to `SidebarListStyle`.  This gives me a `List` that looks like this:

[image]

Great!  However, I would like to set a different background color on it, and can't seem to figure out how to do it.  My code looks like this:

```
List {
   <snip>
}
.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
.background(Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea())
```

But, this effectively does nothing.  My `List` looks exactly the same.  How can I go about setting the background color for this `List`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this modifier `.listRowBackground()` for background color of a separate row.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var items = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    init(){
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .purple // background color of list
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.yellow) // background color of listRow
                Text(item)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.blue) // background color of listRow
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 600)
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: That works fine for the rows themselves.  What about the background of the entire List?  It's still showing as gray.

Comment: @Shadowman you can use `UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor` for background color of list

I updated my post for that :)

Comment: Excellent!  Is there an equivalent for macOS apps that can't make use of UIKit?

Comment: Also, the UITableView.appearance() approach changes *every* List background color.  Is there no way to change them on an individual basis?

Comment: @Shadowman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454752/swiftui-background-color-of-list-mac-os would be a answer to your first ask about using in macOS.


For the second ask,  you can solve it by creating a struct for each list separately.
I am not sure, if there is a way now without `init(){UITableView.appearance()}` for list background color with SwiftUI in iOS

Comment: @Shadowman If my answer was helpful, you can accept my answer :D

Comment: Hi How do I change the disclosure indicator color

Comment: this finally has an answer, see my post

Answer (score 0):

**This is the holy grail as of iOS 16+ and macOS 13+**

```
.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
.background(Color.red)
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
.background(.red.opacity(0.2))
```

Add this to your form, that's it!

Comment: As it is currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75764050/edit) to explain what your code does or add other supporting information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).